# Tmux on start and with previous command

Tags: terminal, zsh, tmux

I can easily start `tmux` on my shell on start, but let's assume:

- Process A => launch a new terminal (process B) with a command
- Process B => just start `tmux` without launching the command passed through.

Any way to handle this (process a launch new terminal with tmux and previous command)?

I'm using the default macOS terminal, so a zsh shell.
In particular, I encountered this error while launching a build with `react-native` that launches the packager in a new terminal.

If I launch `osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "pwd"'`. I expected to get the current directory after launching a new terminal window, but I don't get anything, I just see the shell refreshing with `tmux`.
`Tmux` always autostart (I'm using a simple script), in fact, if I comment on this script, the previous command just prints fine the directory.

The script I'm using to start it (located inside `zshrc`) is:

```
if command -v tmux &> /dev/null && [ -n "$PS1" ] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ screen ]] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ tmux ]] && [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
  exec tmux
fi
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to User User!  My apologies, but I'm struggling to understand your question.  I *think* I can help (I start `tmux` in some interesting ways), but I'm not sure what you are trying to do. We may be having some difficulties around wording -- "process", for instance, has a specific meaning in Linux, and it doesn't quite seem to "fit" the way you are using it.  The same with "terminal", but it *may* be correct.  Can you provide more of an example using "real" names.  What "terminal" are you using?  Also, give a sample "command". Please edit your question with the updates - Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds for sure! I will add the information

Comment: Thanks for updating.  Unfortunately there's still some confusion.  First, you say you are using the *"default MaOS terminal (bash)*".  First, "bash" isn't a terminal - It's a shell.  That's part of the "terminology" problem I mentioned above.  Also, is that supposed to be "macOS"?  If so, then the default shell on macOS is supposed to be `zsh`, which you have in the tags, but don't mention in the question.  And then, in your edit, you mention "this error", but you haven't mentioned an error, nor said what error you are receiving.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, yes it was a "macOS". And I supposed that Big Sur continues to use bash as the shell instead of zsh, but that wasn't correct: from Catalina it's `zsh`.
The error that I'm encountering it's: if process A launches a new terminal with command, the second terminal (the newest window) will just load tmux without running the command passed through

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think it's clear and I reported the mcve: when running a `react-native` it should launch the `packager` in a new terminal, but it just starts a new blank terminal. That's the problem and that's the same as the question...

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I edited the question with a standard command, hoping now it's more clear

Comment: "I'm using a simple script", "if I comment on this script, the previous command just prints fine the directory" – What is in the script? How does the script kick in? (i.e. where do you comment it out? in `.zshrc`? in some setting of the Terminal?).

Comment: The script basically just runs `tmux` after checking if exists and not already running. It starts on `.zhsrc` and I comment it out from it.

Comment: Again: do not only describe, edit the question and add the code there. In this case add the relevant fragment of your `.zshrc`.

Comment: The script it's pretty easy but I edited the question ;)

Comment: Three more things: (1) "Pretty easy" or not, we don't know it until you post it. (2) The question does not state that the "script" you're referring to is in fact a fragment of your `.zshrc`. But it is, isn't it? This should be in the question. (3) We have the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1689543/revisions) and there is no need to litter the question with "EDIT2" and such. In fact the question may benefit from being rebuilt to a more coherent form. Even if you don't do this, the important thing is: the question is now way less vague than it used to be. Way to go.